# CSS Can't scroll down in main content

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to web dev, and am trying to create a minimal (ish) website for my hosting / sys admin business.

So, I've created what I think looks like a pretty nice website so far, but I can't scroll down in the  section, which is obviously a problem.

Additionally, I think I've done some pretty stupid things with regards to CSS, and I'm sure there must be a better way. If you see anything that could be done better, please let me know.

Here's my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Maestoso Digital</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Maestoso Digital logo">
            <ul id="nav-links">
                <li id="active">Home</li>
                <li><a href="hosting.html">Hosting</a></li>
                <li><a href="cloud-management.html">Cloud Deployment</a></li>
                <li><a href="system-admin.html">System Administration</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form action="customers.html">
                <input type="submit" value="Existing Customers" />
            </form>
        </nav>

        <main>
            <div id="header">
                <img id="header-img" src="header.png" alt="Picture of data centre">
                <h1 id="header-title">Welcome</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h1>We are an internet service provider for the modern digital age!</h1>
                <p>Maestoso Digital is an internet service provider offering bespoke, enterprise-grade hosting solutions and system administration services for all, but especially for musicians and musical organisations. Our numerous datacenters around the globe offer ultra-fast performance for whatever your needs may be, and our Network Operations Centre monitor your services 24/7 to ensure that they are always online.</p>

                <div class="features">
                    <img class="" src="" />
                    <img class="" src="" />
                    <img class="" src="" />
                </div>
                <div class="features">
                    <img class="" src="" />
                    <img class="" src="" />
                    <img class="" src="" />
                </div>

                <p>Maestoso Digital is an internet service provider offering bespoke, enterprise-grade hosting solutions and system administration services for all, but especially for musicians and musical organisations. Our numerous datacenters around the globe offer ultra-fast performance for whatever your needs may be, and our Network Operations Centre monitor your services 24/7 to ensure that they are always online.</p>

                <p>Maestoso Digital is an internet service provider offering bespoke, enterprise-grade hosting solutions and system administration services for all, but especially for musicians and musical organisations. Our numerous datacenters around the globe offer ultra-fast performance for whatever your needs may be, and our Network Operations Centre monitor your services 24/7 to ensure that they are always online.</p>

                
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Share Tech", sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed15ac;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ed1c51;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16pt;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

nav img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 20%;
    max-width: 150px;
}


#nav-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav-links:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#nav-existing-customers {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-color: #1a1a1a;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-color: #000;
}

input {
    background-color: #ed15ac;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

input:hover {
    background-color: #ed1c51;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
}

#header-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 310px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 60%;
    font-size: 120px;
}

.features {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;

}

.features>img {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 128px;
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

I'd really appreciate your help, so thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, everything seems fine. Are you loading any other ressources ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the css attribute `overflow` is set to `hidden` on `body` and it applied to the child elements.
To fix the problem, it is needed to update `overflow` attribute on `main` or `#content` element.

```
#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried adding this, and it hasn't solved the problem...

Comment: Actually, solved it. I've just removed `overflow: hidden` altogether, and it's working brilliantly now. Thanks for your help!